# Docker: Unable to connect to a remote Postgres server from a Docker Container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I installed the [Metabase](https://metabase.com) application, created a Docker container (on one Linux host) and I want to connect to a remote Postgres database (on a second Linux host) from the Docker container.  The setup of Metabase allows entry of connection parameters to the Postgres database. Each time I enter the proper connection parameters in Metabase I get a database connection error.  I can connect to the Postgres database from the host running the container using PSQL with no problem. My question is, is there something within Docker or the remote Postgres server that I must setup in order to allow a connection between a Docker container and a remote database? I realize this is normally caused by incorrect host/port information, problems with DNS, firewall blocking or other network problems. I am new to Docker and I do not know where to look or what to setup to make this work. Does anyone have suggestions about how to make this connection work? Thank you!

Comment: From within a docker container, the connection parameters should be identical as on your docker host (assuming the hostname is resolvable within the container). Can you provide us with specific details...exactly how are you trying to connect from within your container? Is outbound access from your container otherwise working?

Comment: When I disabled the firewall on my Linux server hosting Docker, I was able to make the connection to Postgres through Metabase. When the firewall is enabled I cannot make the connection.  I found the below solution works:
 

$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=docker0
success


$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
success


]$ sudo systemctl restart docker

Thanks for the help!